# What features should I look for when buying a external wireless card used for the purpose of pen testing/snooping

Tags: penetration-test, wifi, wireless, wireshark, kali-linux

I'm currently planning to buy an external wireless card for the purpose of pen testing and snooping my own network in order to learn more about it and try to create more preventive measure against this kind of activity.

Currently I have heard that the best External Wireless card for this activity would be the AWUS036H USB-based card from ALFA Networks. However I was between that one and the Alfa Long-Range Dual-Band AC1200 Wireless USB 3.0 Wi-Fi.

I know this question was asked [before](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54677/what-features-should-i-look-for-in-a-wifi-card-used-for-wifi-snooping-penetrat) , However I'm asking again because its been a year since it and the AWUS036H is already becoming old. So I was wondering if there are already better Wi-Fi External cards out there in the market. Which are more efficient, faster, long range and accepting other versions of the IEE signal 802.11 technology such as N,G,B,A,F,C.

(IT needs to be compatible with the distro KALI Linux)

Comment: Isn't this still a duplicate because you are asking "what features" and that answer is still accurate? You could offer a bounty on it (when you have earned enough reputation) asking for an update.